# Plugin'maven' com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException:compileSdkVersion. THESE TWO ERRORS I'M FACHING WITH BUILDING APK USING REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, android-studio, apk, expo-build

the project is developed with React native + expo,

and I'm using the command "./gradlew assambleRelease" to build an APK (android).

and also I've used the expo command to build "expo build"

"./gradlew assambleDebug"
"./gradlew assambleRelease"
"./gradlew assambleRelease --scan"

and i'v tried "./gradlew clean"

after this all i'v used ANDROID STUDIO
installed java11, SDK build tool and got same error.

Comment: Please share the exact and complete error message.